# PTVS lxml code completion does not work

Tags: python, python-3.6, code-completion, ptvs

I am trying to use lxml package to parse XML file.
Simple code work well in python interpreter. 
But,  PTVS code completion does not show anything about package.
Thus I must find everything by look up API document. It feels like i am using Text Editor not IDE.

```
from lxml import etree
etree.parse(path)
```

may I miss something to import package?

Versions:
Windows 10 & VS2017 & Anaconda 4.4.0 & Python 3.6 & lxml 3.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question to PTVS github and here is [answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/2942).

PTVS has an issue with analysing certain libraries.

> There are a variety of issues relating to analysis not correctly understanding certain libraries. This issue is to collect those reports and spin them off into properly researched and understood tracker items.